# why I get Software caused connection abort: socket write error?

Tags: java, sockets, server

I want to send two different objects on the same socket to my client application from my server application. From what I've read I am doing this the right way, but still I cannot send my second object to my client.

Here is my server code:

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

String name = null;
Socket socket = null;

public ServerThread(Socket s, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.socket = s;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        RequestType request = (RequestType) serverInputStream.readObject();
        switch (request) {
            case LOGIN:
                serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                RequestManager.manageLogin(serverOutputStream, serverInputStream);
                serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                RequestManager.managePopulateTable(serverOutputStream);
        }
        serverOutputStream.close();
        serverInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And this is my server request manager

```
public class RequestManager {

public static void manageLogin(ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream, ObjectInputStream serverInputStream) {
    ArrayList<ProductEntity> availableProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        UserEntity loggedUser = (UserEntity) serverInputStream.readObject();
        if (DatabaseManager.userConnect(loggedUser.getUsername(), loggedUser.getPassword())) {
            serverOutputStream.writeObject(loggedUser);
        }
        else
            serverOutputStream.writeObject(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void managePopulateTable(ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream) {
    ArrayList<ProductEntity> availableProducts = DatabaseManager.getProducts();
    try {
        serverOutputStream.writeObject(availableProducts);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The problem occurs when I try to send "availableProducts" to client.

Comment: Stop creating and closing new object streams, and use the same ones for the life of the socket, at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

You've a lot of problems with the following code:

```
ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
...
switch (request) {
    case LOGIN:
        serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ...
        serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

When you open an `ObjectOutputStream`, header information is written to the stream to help manage the object serialization.  Similarly, when you open an `ObjectInputStream`, the header information is read from the stream.

But here, you are opening a second `ObjectInputStream` (which will read header information from the same socket stream) and a second `ObjectOutputStream` (which will write header information to the same socket stream).  As a result, the object streams on the sockets will be in a bad state - object(s) should follow the header information, not another Object Stream header.

Do not open your object stream multiple times.

Comment: For my serverInputStream, if I do not open a second ObjectInputStream it throws "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC". And for serverOutputStream, even if I do not open a second ObjectOutputStream, I get the same error

Comment: Sounds like your client code might be doing something similar, and opening a second `ObjectOutputStream` on the same socket output stream.  Only wrap a socket stream (any stream, actually) once.